# Excluding one of the chapter from starting with an odd numbered page in thesis

Tags: layout, class-options

My university provided me with a LaTeX template for my thesis. In the class file of it, there is a part of the code that makes all the chapters start from an odd-numbered page. However, I need to exclude one of the chapters. How can I do that?

I think the followings are the responsible part of the code:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu %"BolumSagdaKalsiNolu" means "let chapters start from the odd-numbered pages"
                    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                          \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-10\p@}}
                          \if@appendix
                          \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0\p@}}
                              \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}                                        
                                  \else
                              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter. \protect \bf{#1}}
                                  \fi
                    \else
                      \relax
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi
                    }
```

And:

```
\def\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu{
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd
      \c@page
    \else
      \hbox{}
      %\thispagestyle{empty}
      \newpage
      \if@twocolumn
    \hbox{}
    \newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Can I add something like that?:

```
if(chapter_name == "blabla")
    don't apply "bolumsagdakalsinnolu"
```

Comment: Tray `{\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage\chapter{...}}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo is it going to work without ``\def`` ?

Comment: \let redefines \cleardoublepage, while \chapter simply exicutes inside the group.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have placed right before the relevant table environment in the appendix part with this: ``{\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage\chapter{APPENDIX A}}`` and still didn't work...

Comment: A book class `\chapter` starts with `\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi` while yours starts with `\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu`, and I have no iidea what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a switch, similar to the standard book class:

```
\newif\ifopenright\openrighttrue
\def\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifopenright
      \ifodd
        \c@page
      \else
        \hbox{}
        %\thispagestyle{empty}
        \newpage
        \if@twocolumn
          \hbox{}
          \newpage
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Now, you can use `\openrightfalse` to deactivate opening on odd pages and `\openrighttrue` to reactivate it.

Here a complete example with standard class `report`, your `\@chapter` code and my adapted `\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@appendix% Added because the code below uses it.
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu %"BolumSagdaKalsiNolu" means "let chapters start from the odd-numbered pages"
                    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                          \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-10\p@}}
                          \if@appendix
                          \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0\p@}}
                              \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}                                        
                                  \else
                              \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter. \protect \bf{#1}}
                                  \fi
                    \else
                      \relax
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi
                    }
\newif\ifopenright\openrighttrue
\def\BolumSagdaKalsinNolu{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifopenright
      \ifodd
        \c@page
      \else
        \hbox{}
        %\thispagestyle{empty}
        \newpage
        \if@twocolumn
          \hbox{}
          \newpage
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
This should be an odd page.
\chapter{Second chapter}
This should be an odd page.
\openrightfalse
\chapter{Third chapter}
This should be an even page.
\openrighttrue
\chapter{Forth chapter}
This should be an odd page.
\chapter{Fifth chapter}
This should be an odd page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test my suggestion, because you've not posted a minimal working example.

Comment: I see, you are right. But the project folder is very huge and I don't know how to minimize it. By the way, your answer didn't work :/

Comment: @Emr As I've shown, my code does work basically. If it does not work with your template, there is additional code, you've not posted. So we need more information. Best would be a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but still don't work. If you have time I ask you if you can use the following drive link to download the actual class file. Maybe you can do something new. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BI2Sgzj-4BgTk0a4-aFqA9fdwklFS-43/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Emr Can you please add a minimal working example to your question. With the downloaded class, I always have several error messages, because of undefined macros, e.g., `\th@Instituteiki` and many more.